# How to change format of data in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am working with some integrations. I get data in Javascript file and I need to change the format slightly.

The data is received by Javascript in the following format:

```
["{label=Created By ID, value=Contact_ID__r.CreatedById}",
"{label=Created Date, value=Contact_ID__r.CreatedDate}",
...]
```

I need to convert the data in the following format in order to pass it ahead:

```
[{"label":"Start Date","value":"Contract_Start_Date__c"},
{"label":"Created Date", "value":"Contact_ID__r.CreatedDate"},
...]
```

I tried using `JSON.stringify()` and `.replace()` in various combinations to change the format. Eg: `data[i].replace(/"/g, '')`. Nothing worked. I am not able to change the format.

Please help. Thank You!

### **More Info:**

The data is received from apex(just like java) in the form of `Map<Map<String,String>,String>`.

Eg:`["{label=Created By ID, value=Contact_ID__r.CreatedById}","account"}]`

In javascript, I extracted `Map<String,String>` part of it as follows:

```js
//result.data contains the data returned by apex method.
//Variable availableOptionsForAccountFields will be used to display the data.

            var iterator = 0;
            var keys = Object.keys(result.data); //store the keys.
            Object.keys(result.data).forEach(fieldToBeAddedAsAvailableOption => { //loop over the returned data.
                //Identify the object of the field and add it to respective variable so that it can be displayed to the user
                if (result.data[keys[iterator]] == 'account') {
                    this.availableOptionsForAccountFields.push(fieldToBeAddedAsAvailableOption);
                }
                iterator = iterator+1;
            });

//After execution of this loop, the variable availableOptionsForAccountFields will have all the values to be displayed in dual listbox.
```

After extracting the data, I am left with the following data:

```
["{label=Created By ID, value=Contact_ID__r.CreatedById}"]
```

I need to convert this data into the following format so that I can display it using HTML:

```
[{"label":"Start Date", "value":"Contract_Start_Date__c"}]
```

Comment: The input string you want to process is not JSON (JSON doesn't use `=`). You will need to build a parser, and to do that you'll need to acquire the grammar or BNF syntax for the data you want to process because it looks like it can contain raw strings and you'll need to know how to escape or encode certain characters (e.g. what if a `label` text contains quotes, commas or equals signs?)

Comment: Instead can you just ask whoever created this random format simply to output it in valid JSON in the first place?

Comment: @ADyson the data comes in the form of `Map<Map<String,String>,String>`. I extracted the `Map<String,String>` part of it and I am left with `"{label=Created By ID, value=Contact_ID__r.CreatedById}"`.

Comment: @Dai The text `label` and `value` will not change. Only the part after `=` will change.Thanks for responding. I will research more on how I can build a parser for this.

Comment: `Map<Map<String,String>,String>`...what is this exactly? It doesn't look like JS code. Is it some C# maybe? Anyway if it's your code which generates it, then you should be able to fix it. This will be easier than building a parser in the vast majority of scenarios. If you need help with fixing your data format, please show us more clearly/fully what you're doing.

Comment: @ADyson Looks like TypeScript to me.

Comment: @ADyson I have updated the question and added more details. Thanks!

Comment: You need to amend the apex code to output proper JSON. I don't have knowledge of that language but I'm sure it will have a JSON library either built in or easily available which will serialise objects and lists to valid JSON automatically

Comment: @ADyson Okay... I will look into it. Thanks a lot!